# Adding WPF Components Using Entity Framework in C # / SQL Server

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Name="msg1" Height="71" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="389.333" Background="#FFE4E4E4">
    <Ellipse x:Name="photo_Copy" Height="46.5" Width="47.023" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="14.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.473,0.482">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="user11.png"/>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Height="19.251" Canvas.Left="63.876" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Paulinho da Serra" Canvas.Top="10" Width="131.334"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy" Height="19.251" Canvas.Left="313.999" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="07/01/2017" Canvas.Top="10" Width="65.334"/>
    <Canvas Height="31.749" Canvas.Left="63.876" Canvas.Top="29.251" Width="315.457" Background="#FFD4D4D4">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Height="31.749" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Olá, Bom dia!" Width="295.457" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

It will be responsible for loading a text message into your textblock1, which will come from the database... and this entire `Canvas` is inside a `Scrollviewer`. I wish when I had more than one message, he would repeat this `Canvas` within the `Scrollviewer`, and stay on top of the first ... some light? I can not think of anything.

Answer (score 0):

you receive multiple messages and you want to display them in a TextBlock!
the better way to do that instead of text box use a ListBox to display them.
make a list of messages in code designer and bind it to ListBox in code xaml.

Comment: But, how to draw the canvas to each list item?